# How to nest lists within sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, lists

I'm working with a sentence that looks like this:

> John thinks that there is a problem with department X because "picking an item from department X and moving it to another department" will crash the system, but Mark claim's that's not the cases since "creating a new item, assigning it to department X, and moving it to another department" will not crash the system.

Here I am using double quotes to wrap the lists, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What research have you done, and what question do you have about what you found?

Comment: I could use a bulleted or numbered vertical list, but I'm trying to keep it horizontal. I've looked at examples that use a colon to show where the list starts and numbers prior to each listed item, but I would also like to show where the list ends.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+make+a+list+in+sentence+form

Comment: I don't see an example that makes it clear where the lists end.

Comment: End your list when you end your sentence: *I went to the store for: a) peaches; b) cream; and c) sardines.* Or: *John failed the interview for four reasons: he was late; he was unshaven; he did not know the subject matter; and he was not dressed appropriately.*

Comment: My lists don't end where my sentence ends.

Comment: @Davo: In essence, the OP is referring to a **single algorithm**, but he's describing the algorithm by listing its steps  (as opposed to naming the algorithm). The OP's sentence would be closer to something like "Team John-Tim-Robert defeated team William-Jenny-Tom by a margin of three points", where he refers to teams by listing the members' names, but is essentially always referring to a single team, not many names. That's different from your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really specific to English, it's a stylistic choice to enhance readability.

You describe it as a list. However, I would suggest that it's more correct to call this a **sequence**. You're not listing random examples, you're describing **a particular algorithm**. But instead of referring to it by a name, you are referring to it by listing its steps.

You're trying to explain something that's rather complex. To further complicate matters, the sequences are very much defined by the operations (in the **specific** order that you list them). So it's imperative that you describe this as clearly as possible to your reader.

To make a programming analogy, I would **declare** the algorithms first, and then later refer to the declared algorithms. This dramatically simplifies your sentence structure.

*To extend the programming analogy: you're trying to inline several complex calculations; you should instead try to list each calculation separately to enhance the readability.*

> The application crashed when John tried to do the following:
>
> 1. Picking an item from department X
> 2. Moving the item to another department
>
> John suggests that there is a problem with department X. However, Mark claims that that's not the case, since the following does not result in a crash:
>
> 1. Creating a new item
> 2. Assigning it to department X
> 3. Moving the item to another department.

Note that from now on, you can refer to these as "John's method" and "Mark's method", or any similarly applicable name.

For example:

> **Mark's method** proves that the application is able to move items between departments. The problem with **John's method** could be caused by something different, e.g. a data issue with the specific item that John selected.

---

Note the difference between using **bullet points** and **numbering**:

> The following actions crash the system:
>
> - Clicking on the red button
> - Clicking on the green button
> - Clicking on the blue button

This implies that any of the listed actions **by themselves** can cause the application to crash. Compare this to:

> The following actions crash the system:
>
> 1. Clicking on the red button
> 2. Clicking on the green button
> 3. Clicking on the blue button

This implies that the crash occurs when you click the buttons **in this particular order**.

---

*There are other ways to convey the same message, e.g. referring to it as a "sequence of events" or "algorithm", as opposed to "actions". This is a bit more context-specific though.*